# In LilyPond, can I automatically center markup on a slur/tie?

Tags: lilypond, engraving

For some teaching examples I'm making, I'm looking to label slurs and ties. I'd like the label to be placed in the center of the slur automatically, much like LaTeX's `midway` stipulation. I can move the labels by brute force (as shown below), but is it possible to do it automatically?

```
\version "2.18.2"

\score {
  \relative c' {
    <c e g>1(_\markup \halign #-7 "X" | % I don't want to have to do that every time!
    <c f a>) |
  }
  \layout { }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a starting point.

```
\version "2.20.0"
#(define ((myCallBack  string) grob)
   (grob-interpret-markup grob
     (if (= (ly:grob-property grob 'direction) 1)
         (markup #:translate '(1 . 3) #:center-column (
                                                        string
                                                        (#:stencil (ly:slur::print grob))))
         (markup  #:center-column (
                                    (#:stencil (ly:slur::print grob))
                                    ( string))))))


{
  \override Slur #'stencil = #(myCallBack "XX")
  c'2 (  c'' c d'' )
}
```

[image]

Adapted from https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/lilypond-user/2009-06/msg00211.html